# Overriding method what is used by other method in parent - best practices

Tags: python, inheritance, design-patterns

In general - do or don't?
Consistent with pythonic way of thinking?
Example:

```
class A(object):
    def test_2(self):
        self.test_3()

    def test_3(self):
        raise Exception()


class B(A):
    def test_3(self):
        print 'B'
        pass
```

Usage:

```
b = B()
b.test_2()
```

If condition added: `test_3` is private and `test_2` public - it justifies such construction?
If condition added: `A` is abstract class

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle

Comment: what is your intention here? do you want `A` to be an abstract base class?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Making `A` abstract justify such construction?

Comment: Yes, it's totally OK, in fact you don't even need to define dummy in the parent.